# Golang-migrate returns "no change"

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, golang-migrate

I'm starting learn Go and SQL. I tryed to make initial migration using golang-migrate in my go project. Database is postgresql

This is migration file:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id serial not null unique,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    username varchar(255) not null unique,
    password_hash varchar(255) not null,
)

CREATE TABLE todo_lists
(
    id serial not null unique,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE users_lists
(
    id serial not null unique,
    user_id int references users (id) on delete cascade not null,
    list_id int references todo_lists (id) on delete cascade not null,
);

CREATE TABLE todo_items
(
    id serial not null unique,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255),
    done boolean not null default false,
);

CREATE TABLE lists_items
(
    id serial not null unique,
    item_id int references todo_items (id) on delete cascade not null,
    list_id int references todo_lists (id) on delete cascade not null,
);
```

The command I use:

`migrate -path ./schema -database 'postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/to_do?sslmode=disable' up`

And bash returns:

`no change` (without any error)

Where can be problem?

Comment: Were the tables created?

Comment: No.  Only created database "to_do"

Comment: What are `schema_migrations` table values?

Comment: 2 Columns: 'Version' with value 1 and 'Dirty' with false

Answer (score 0):

I put together a small guide to help you solve your issue. Please be sure to follow along and you would be good to go!

##### Run Postgres

To run the Postgres instance I used to test my solution I used the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
```

This command spins up an instance of Postgres with these two things:

1. It sets up the port mapping (the port `5432` on your machine is mapped to the port `5432` of your Docker container).
2. It sets the password for the `postgres` user to `postgres` (just for the sake of the demo).

##### Create the migration scripts

To create the first migration script, I used the following command:

```
migrate create -ext sql -dir db/migrations -seq create_users_table
```

Thanks to this command, I was able to create the folder path `db/migrations` and two files within it (one for the `up` migration and one for the `down` one).

##### Fill the files with the code

The next step was to fill the above-created files with the `CREATE` and `DROP` statements. Let's start with the `up` one.

###### `000001_create_users_table.up.sql` file

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
(
    id serial not null unique,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    username varchar(255) not null,
    password_hash varchar(255) not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo_lists
(
    id serial not null unique,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_lists
(
    id serial not null unique,
    user_id int references users (id) on delete cascade not null,
    list_id int references todo_lists (id) on delete cascade not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo_items
(
    id serial not null unique,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255),
    done boolean not null default false
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lists_items
(
    id serial not null unique,
    item_id int references todo_items (id) on delete cascade not null,
    list_id int references todo_lists (id) on delete cascade not null
);
```

To make the migration idempotent I added the `IF NOT EXISTS` check. Take this as a best practice when you're about to write migrations.

###### `000001_create_users_table.down.sql` file

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users_lists;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lists_items;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo_lists;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo_items;
```

The same applies here with the `IF EXISTS` check. Pay attention to the order in which you're deleting stuff as you can easily get into error due to objects' dependencies.

##### Run migrations

To run this migration, **be sure that the to_do DB is created**.
To apply the migration run:

```
migrate -database 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/to_do?sslmode=disable' -path ./db/migrations up
```

With this, you'll get this output: `1/u create_users_table (44.392422ms)`.
If you run this twice, the second output will be: `no change`.

When you want to undo the migration, you've to run the following statement:

```
migrate -database 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/to_do?sslmode=disable' -path ./db/migrations down
```

This will undo all of the migrations applied so far. For a deeper understanding, please refer to the official doc: https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate#cli-usage.

Let me know if this solves your issue or if you need anything else!

Comment: Is it important to use Docker? I resolve again 'no change' output. I check db to_do without any changes

Comment: you can also skip the usage of Docker. It's a fast and convenient way to run a Postgres instance. Maybe try to follow my guide with the usage of Docker, you shouldn't face any problem

Comment: I tryed this with Docker and again 'no change' output. May be I skip one more step before using migration? (db in Docker created)

Comment: There is no other step in between. What is the content of the migrations table?

Comment: 2 columns: version: 1; dirty: false

Comment: weird, you can reach me out if you want to clarify your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251000/discussion-between-aaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-and-ivan-pesenti).

Comment: I resolve this problem by deleting migration table and correcting sql file (delete ',')

Comment: Good to know! I forgot to mention this change when I dropped the answer omg

Comment: Another potential cause is a bad file name. I had `1_create_tables_up.sql` (note: `_up.sql` instead of `.up.sql`). I saw the same symptoms: ran with message of "no changes" and resulted in `schema_migrations` record of version: 1, dirty: false.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by deleting migration table and correcting sql file (delete ',' in every string of last columns)

Comment: what you mean by delete ',' in every string of last columns? I have simple query CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY (
  user_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPZ,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPZ
); and it fails

Comment: Make from this `id serial not null unique,` to this `id serial not null unique`